# Pass PHP requests on to PHP-FPM using sockets

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, php

I was trying to set up linux-dash on my server running gunicorn with nginx as reverse proxy. I tried setting up the configuration file as suggested [here](https://gist.github.com/sergeifilippov/8909839). 
Every time I try to open one of the php scripts in the browser, it throws a "**404 not found**" error. As far as I understand the following block in the configuration file is responsible for it.

```
location ~ \.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    #fastcgi_pass localhost:9000; # using TCP/IP stack
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Can someone help me understand what the condition in the if block actually means? And where am I going wrong? 
As far as the location directive is concerned, what I understand from it is that it tries to find if a php script needs to be executed and accordingly splits the path to the script and somehow using fastcgi runs that script on the browser. Please correct me if I am wrong and provide a better understanding of what it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is checking for the existence of file. Ensure the path exists. You should try to use `try_files` instead.

http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Check_IF_File_Exists

http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#try_files